# JavaScript countdown from php timestamp difference

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timestamp, countdown

I'd like to countdown time which is difference between two time from php, the result is timestamp.

```
{var $time = new \DateTime()}        

<div class="date" data-date="{= ($time2->getTimestamp() - $time->getTimestamp())*1000}">
```

In data-date I have difference of time [timestamp]. Now I want to countdown this time. I get this information from HTML to JS.

```
$(function() {        
    $(".date").each(function(){         
        time = $(this).data('date');        
        $.countdown($(this).children(".countdown"), time);
    });
});
```

There is taken code which doesn't work properly.

```
jQuery.countdown = function(selector, datevalue) {

                    var amount = datevalue;

        // catch past dates
        if(amount < 0){
            $(selector).html("Done");
        }

        // date is in the future, calculate the diff
        else{
            days=0;hours=0;mins=0;secs=0;out="";

            amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);//kill the "milliseconds" so just secs

            days=Math.floor(amount/86400);//days
            amount=amount%86400;

            hours=Math.floor(amount/3600);//hours
            amount=amount%3600;

            mins=Math.floor(amount/60);//minutes
            amount=amount%60;

            secs=Math.floor(amount);//seconds

            //if(days != 0){out += days +" day"+((days!=1)?"s":"")+", ";}
                            //if(days == 0) {
                                if(days != 0 || hours != 0){out += ((hours<10)?"0":"") + hours +":";}
                                if(days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0){out += ((mins<10)?"0":"") + mins +":";}
                                out += ((secs<10)?"0":"") + secs;
                                $(selector).html(out);
                            //}
            // run it all again
            setTimeout(function() {  
                $.countdown(selector, datevalue);
            }, 1000); 

        }

};
```

The time from JS is on the right place but it doesn't countdown.

Comment: How should that work if you are giving the timeout the amount of 1 second ?

Comment: `time = parseInt($(this).data('date'),10);` perhaps?

Comment: and if you remove   `amount = Math.floor(amount/1000);//kill the "milliseconds" so just secs`, you can remove the *1000 from your php

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: you do not decrease **datevalue** variable. So its the same for all iterations

Look at the example below it works fine

```
jQuery.countdown = function(selector, datevalue) {

    var amount = datevalue;

    // catch past dates
    if(amount < 0){
        $(selector).html("Done");
    }

    // date is in the future, calculate the diff
    else{
        datevalue--;
        $(selector).html(datevalue);
        setTimeout(function() {  
            $.countdown(selector, datevalue);
        }, 1000); 
    }
};

$.countdown('.date', 10);​​​
```